# how to print only a part of each element of a list in python output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have this code that I shortened a bit to be within character limit as shown below in python 3

```
import re

seqs = """>UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASIEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLIIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLFSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQE
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYT
>UDW38242.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQE
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAILMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYT
>UDW38252.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQQ
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYT
>UDW38263.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIXVSXTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSXXXXXXXX
XNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQE
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYT
"""
seq2 = seqs.replace("\n","")
list = seq2.split(">")
list.pop(0)

rbd = re.finditer(r'RV[NVSFGYLPTAKRICDQEWH]{219,219}NF',seqs.replace("\n", ""))

for x in rbd:
    
    print(x + " has the rbd domain" + str(x.span()) + "\n")
```

The output I get is shown below

```
UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASIEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLIIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLFSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT has the rbd domain(369, 592)

UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASIEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLIIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLFSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT has the rbd domain(1693, 1916)

UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASIEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLIIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLFSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT has the rbd domain(3017, 3240)

UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASIEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLIIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLFSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT has the rbd domain(4341, 4564)
```

For the most part I am very happy with this output but I want it to be a little less wordy, so how would I make it so I can print only the indication for each sequence

```
"UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+), UDW38242.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+), etc
```

I was thinking I could use something like `print(x, end = (+) + " has the rbd domain" + str(x.span()) + "\n")` since each indication ends with a `(+)` but I'm not so sure how to use the end function along with print or if even this is the best way to do it

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-50-python-end-parameter-in-print/ What is your problem it is not clear what you would like to transform your output to.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to leave out, since you wrote "etc." in the description.

Comment: @AndrewRyan I want something that looks like "UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+) has the rbd domain (###, ###)." instead of what I have currently. Essentially a more concise output.

Comment: Where do you assign `x`?

Comment: BTW, if you're working with FASTA files, there are libraries to help.

Comment: @Barmar I apologize, that was a mistake, I fixed it

Comment: Is `n.span()` supposed to be `x.span()` now?

Comment: Anyway, use a regular expression to extract the part of the line that you want to print. There's no need to use `end=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to get everything up to `(+)` and print just that.

```
for x in rbd:
    indication = re.search(r'^.*\(\+\)', x.group(0)).group(0)
    print(f"{indication} has the rbd domain{x.span()}\n")
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error that states "expected string or bytes-like object" for the (+) regex

Comment: Wait a second. How is the regexp `RV[NVSFGYLPTAKRICDQEWH]{219,219}NF` matching the indicator that ends with `(+)`?

Comment: No that regexp is for a string that I am searching for within seqs. specifically rbd = """
RVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLN
DLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRK
SNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPK
KSTNLVKNKCVNF"""

Comment: But the loop `for x in rbd` is iterating over those results. So how does `x.group(0)` contain `(+)`?